# Text to Speech is not working during an incoming call in android

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I want to play a text sequence as speech during an incoming call , lowering the ringtone for few seconds. I've sent the string via intent from a broadcast receiver to another class file.
The text is displayed if I use it in toast during call but the speech doesn't play.
the code for text to speech in my class file is :-

```
public class callName extends Activity {

    String call;

    TextToSpeech tts;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        call = extras.getString("sms");

        tts = new TextToSpeech(this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {

            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                    tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
                }
            }
        });

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), call, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        tts.speak(call, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

tts has not been initialize when you call speak, you have to move your speak code inside `onInit()`

```
tts = new TextToSpeech(this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {

        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
                tts.speak(call, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
            }
        }
    });
```